# Flutter Dynamic Textfield Autocompletion

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I use the library autocomplete_textfield to create a textfield with autocompletion. Every time the text is changed I make a request to fetch a specific list of users and then set them to the suggestion of my AutocompleteTextfield. The list seems to be updated (when I print(list.length)) but visually it isn't. Any idea?

My AutocompletionTextfield:

```
AutoCompleteTextField<User>(
  textChanged: (item) async {
    await model.searchRecommendation(item);
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)
    ),
    labelText: 'Recommendations', 
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColors.blackColor)
  ),
  key: autocompleteUserSearchTextFieldKey,
  suggestionsAmount: 3,
  controller: _userSearchController,
  itemSubmitted: (item) {},
  suggestions: model.userRecommendations,
  itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) => new Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text(suggestion.email)
    ),
  ),
  itemSorter: (a, b) => a.email.compareTo(b.email),
  itemFilter: (suggestion, input) => suggestion.email.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase()),
),
```

my viewmodel:

```
List<User> userRecommendations = [];

Future searchRecommendation(String filter) async {
  var token = await SharedPreferenceUtils().getStringValue('jwt');
  final response = await _api.filterUserSearch(filter, currentUser, token);
  if (response is SuccessState) {
    List<dynamic> tmp = response.value.payload;
    tmp ??= [];
    userRecommendations = List<User>.from(tmp.map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));
    notifyListeners();
  } else if (response is ErrorState) {
    String error = response.msg;
    print('Error $error');
  } else {
    print('Error');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nvm I found the answer! `AutocompleteTextfield` has a method called `updateSuggestions()`. I just had to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see all of your code, but I assume the widget tree isn't being rebuilt. You have to wrap `AutoCompleteTextField` with `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` (depending on your implementation, anyway `StreamBuilder` seems more appropriate there) that listens to recommendations result.

You could also implement `StatefulWidget` or use `StatefulBuilder`.

Example with `StatefulBuilder` (it's dirty but should work, ideally you'd use `StreamBuilder`):

```dart
return StatefulBuilder(
  builder: (context, setState) => AutoCompleteTextField<User>(
    textChanged: (item) async {
      await model.searchRecommendation(item);
      setState(() {});
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)),
        labelText: 'Recommendations',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColors.blackColor)),
    key: autocompleteUserSearchTextFieldKey,
    suggestionsAmount: 3,
    controller: _userSearchController,
    itemSubmitted: (item) {},
    suggestions: model.userRecommendations,
    itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) => new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: ListTile(title: Text(suggestion.email)),
    ),
    itemSorter: (a, b) => a.email.compareTo(b.email),
    itemFilter: (suggestion, input) => suggestion.email.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase()),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Should I combine provider & streambuilder?

Comment: Actually I think it is being rebuilt because notifyListeners is called after searchRecommendation(item).

Comment: if that's the case, try implementing `didUpdateWidget` (unless you already have something that's listening for the changes),  `notifyListeners` will not rebuild the tree by itself. You have to have a listener in the tree.  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html 
 https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPosition/notifyListeners.html

Comment: I used an other method to solve this, but thanks for your help!